# Is "out of" instead of "from" colloquial, always okay or simply wrong?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Here is an example sentence, written by a pupil of mine:

> Through the British Empire, which resulted **out of** Britain's urge to build up its economy, Britain was connected to a lot of different countries

The sentence clearly has several issues, but I am only interested in one of them here. I would only use "result from", as a native British English speaker. My pupil has one American parent and one German parent, and lives in Germany.

Would "result out of" be acceptable in written, academic American English? Can it be said at all?

Comment: I think the term that has been mangled here is "grew out of...", but "resulted from..." is more applicable here.

Comment: *Resulted out of an urge* is an infelicity, not a grammatical error. (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=resulted+from%2Cresulted+out+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cresulted%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresulted%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Was not aware that infelicitous had a noun! Thx for that :) Tim, do I presume rightly that you would then, as I am a teacher, advise me to write "clumsy" next to the phrase rather than give a "preposition" mistake?

Comment: Since requests can't have a truth value, Grice gave them a felicity value. Some speech acts are felicitous, like _Could you close the window?_, and some are infelicitous in most contexts, like _I christen this ship the USS_ Dreadlock. It was part of his ["Cooperative Principle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle), which led to Grice's Maxims.  And _from_ is normally required by _result_; the head governs the preposition, and its meaning is irrelevant, like _look at_ and _listen to_.

Answer (score 1):

If you search Google Books for AE, you will find the use of ***result out of*** recorded, but scarce.

[image]

In its definition of the verb *result*, [AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=result) gives 2 examples with ***from***, not with ***out of***:

> - damage that *resulted **from*** the storm;
> - charges that *resulted **from*** the investigation.

So you are safe recommending your pupil (who might have graduated college by now!) to use ***result from***, rather than the other variant, which although not incorrect, sounds less idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Based purely on my past experience as a foreigner in the US, the phrase "something is made out of something" seems much more common to me than "something is made from something". I know this is a different case but bear with me. It seems to me that Americans tend to think of "out of" as meaning the same as "from" and sometimes make this substitution in surprising context, as in "I just came out of the Philippines and man, it was hot there!", etc. So it wouldn't surprise me at all if your student heard "something results out of something" at home or made that extrapolation on their own.